# How many 10 letter words can be formed using a,b,c,d,e,f with the following condition

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many $10$ letter words are there using the letters a,b,c,d,e,f if
(a) the letters in the word appear in alphabetical order?
(b) each letter occurs at least once and the letters in the word appear in alphabetical order?

**My Understanding**:

(a) We count all possible 10-element multisets of $$\{\infty.a, \infty.b, \infty.c, \infty.d, \infty.e, \infty.f\}$$
and for every such multiset, there is only one permutation and given us the alphabetical order. We can count these using stars-bars approcach

Is this right?

Comment: This question is from the book "principles and techniques in combinatrics" exercise 1 Q.59. I tried the first two parts and not able to get my head around these two. So if you can help

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: It would be worth adding your observation about solving the non-negative integer sum to $10$ to the body of your Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: This is a direct application of [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)). In the first case, you can place the "bars" right next to each other, or at the beginning or the end; in the second, you need a "star" on either side of each "bar."

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes I got it. Thank you so much. I guess I knew the concept but was not able to apply it.